# query to postgresql does not work via NPGSQL

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, heidisql

But this query work fine via HeidiSQL.

```
public void InsertUser(String name,String secret)
    {
        if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            String insertStr = "INSERT INTO \"users_cat\" (\"UserName\",\"UserSecret\",\"RegDT\") VALUES('" +
            name+"','"+secret+"','"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+"')";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(insertStr);
            var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(insertStr, conn);
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

NPGSQL throw exception - "relation "users_cat" does not exist". If run this

> INSERT INTO "users_cat" ("UserName","UserSecret","RegDT")
>   VALUES('rtyjrtjrt','trjjttrj','23.04.2020 10:56:09')

query in HeidiSQL, data puts to table without any problems.Where is different NPQSL from HeidiSQL ?

Comment: As you seem to use those dreaded quoted identifiers for column names (which is a [bad idea](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)), maybe the table isn't actually named `"users_cat"`, but maybe `"User_Cat"` or `"USER_CAT"` or any other combination of upper/lowercase

Comment: Apart from checking upper and lower case, make sure you are connected to the same database and that `search_path` is set the same.

Comment: Laurenz Albe you right.Problem was in the selecting miscorrect database.